# Convert startdate and enddate to unix time with react-jsonschema-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unix

I use this library to build my forms: https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form and I have a uischema for date inputs, but when I send the form I want to convert startdate and enddate in unix time.

Here is the code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

import React, { Component, FormGroup, FormControl,ControlLabel } from 'react';
import NavBar from '../Header/NavBar';
import * as dropdown from "../../helpers/dropdown";
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";
import * as formSubmit from "../../helpers/sumary";
import * as moment from 'moment';


class Sumary extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          activityschema: {},
          machineschema: {},
          activitiesTypes: [],
          startDate: moment(),
          endDate: moment(),
          activityType: 0,
          step: 0
        };
    }
    componentWillMount = async () => {
        const activitiesTypes = await dropdown.getActivitiesType();
        const machines = await dropdown.getMachines();
        this.setState({
            activityschema: {
                type: "object",
                properties: {
                  typeNameId: {
                    type: 'number',
                    title: 'Type:',
                    enum: activitiesTypes.map((item) => {
                      return item.id;
                    }),
                    enumNames: activitiesTypes.map((item) => {
                      return item.name;
                    })
                  },
                  startDate: {type: "string", title: 'Start date:'},
                  endDate: {type: "string", title: 'End date:'},
                }
                
              },
            machineschema: {
                type: "object",
                properties: {
                  machinesId: {
                    type: 'number',
                    title: 'Machine Name:',
                    enum: machines.map((item) => {
                      return item.id;
                    }),
                    enumNames: machines.map((item) => {
                      return item.name;
                    })
                  },
                  //startDate: {type: "string", title: 'Start date:'},
                  //endDate: {type: "string", title: 'End date:'},
                }
              },
            uiSchema: {
              startDate: {
                "ui:widget": "date"
                },
              endDate: {
                "ui:widget": "date"
                }
              }
     });
    };
    onSubmit = async ({formData}) => {
      if (formData.typeNameId === 10) {
        this.setState({
          step: 1,
          formData: {
            ...this.state.formData, 
            ...formData
          },
        });
        await formSubmit.getSumary(formData);
        console.log(formData);
      } else {
        await formSubmit.getSumary(formData);
        console.log(formData);
      }
    };
    render () {
      let schema= null;
      schema = this.state.activityschema;
      let uiSchema = this.state.uiSchema;
      switch(this.state.step){
        case 1:
        schema = this.state.machineschema; 
        break;
        default:
        break; 

      }
    return (
      <Form
       schema={schema}
       uiSchema={uiSchema}
       onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
       formData={this.state.formData} />
    );
    }
   }
export default Sumary;
```

The code above works fine, but when I submit data, my formData in startDate and endDate are on this type of format:

```
Object {typeNameId: 3, startDate: "2017-12-22", endDate: "2017-12-27"}
```

But I want them in unix time.

I tryed something like this:

```
onSubmit = async ({formData}) => {
      this.state.formData.startDate.unix();
      this.state.formData.endDate.unix();
      if (formData.typeNameId === 10) {
        this.setState({
          step: 1,
          formData: {
            ...this.state.formData, 
            ...formData
          },
        });
        await formSubmit.getSumary(formData);
        console.log(formData);
      } else {
        await formSubmit.getSumary(formData);
        console.log(formData);
      }
    };
```

But this will get:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'startDate' of
>   undefined

Answer (score 0):

So I see following problems with your code:

1. You don't have `formData` in your `React` initial state.
2. If you want to use `formData` with your `state` you need to track `onChange` event to get the latest data
3. In your `onSubmit` if you use `formData` that you get in `onSubmit` call, it should be enough to remove Rejection error
4. Date has a format of `string`, so it's not exactly moment object, you need to construct it from the string and convert to unix format
5. If you want to input with type `date` you need to specify format on your schema object, otherwise it's just a text input field

You are right in your approach, there seems to be no straight forward way to do this, without adding additional widgets or fields.

Hope this helps.